# Creating and updating nested objects in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I got nested JSON data from the server like this:

```
{
  name: "Alice",
  profile: {
    something: "abc"
  }
}
```

and I have the following model:

```
App.User = Ember.Object.extend({
  name: null,
  profile: Ember.Object.extend({
    something: null
  })
})
```

If I simply do `App.User.create(attrs)` or `user.setProperties(attrs)`, the `profile` object gets overwritten by plain JS object, so currently I'm doing this:

```
var profileAttr = attrs.profile;
delete attrs.profile
user.setProperties(attrs); // or user = App.User.create(attrs);
user.get('profile').setProperties(profileAttrs);
```

It works, but I've got it in a few places and in the real code I've got more than one nested object, so I was wondering if it's ok to override `User#create` and `User#setProperties` methods to do it automatically. Maybe there's some better way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is using javascript setters and getter properties to watch for changes a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20388229/is-using-javascript-setters-and-getter-properties-to-watch-for-changes-a-bad-ide)

Comment: Why do you want `profile` to be an instance of `Ember.Object` specifically? Observers on `profile.something` should work regardless.

Comment: @PascalZajac The main issue I've got is with updating nested objects. If `user.profile` has 2 properties (e.g. `name` and `email`) and only one of them changes and I get data from the server like `data = {user: {profile: {name: 'Bob'}}}`, then doing simply `user.setProperties(data)` will overwrite the whole `user.profile` object including `user.profile.email`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you want the automatic merging behaviour you get with models (the sort of thing you get with `.extend()`). In that case, you could try registering a custom transformer, something like:

```
App.ObjectTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
    deserialize: function(json){
        return Ember.Object.create(json);
    }
});
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    profile: DS.attr('object')
});
```

See: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#json-transforms

Comment: Thanks! Does `ember-model` have similar feature?

Comment: Sorry, I'm only familiar with Ember Data so I don't know, but at the least, you know what feature to go searching for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing your server requests without an adapter you can use the model class method `load()`  with either an array of json objects or a single object.  This will refresh any known records already cached and stash away the JSON for future primary key based lookups.  You can also call `load()` on a model instance with a JSON hash as well but it will only update that single model instance.

Its unclear why you are not using an adapter, you can extend one of the Ember Model adapters and override the the record loading there, eg. extend from the `RESTAdapter` and do any required transform on the JSON if required by overriding `_loadRecordFromData`

You can also override your models `load` function to transform data received if required as well.  The Ember Model source is fairly easy to read so its not hard to extend to your requirements.